# Delete and Insert Inside one Transaction SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just want to ask if it is always the first query will be executed when encapsulate to a transaction? for example i got 500 k records to be deleted and 500 k to be inserted, is there a possibility of locking?
Actually I already test this query and it works fine but i want to make sure if my assumption is correct.

Note: this will Delete and Insert the same record with possible update on other columns.

```
BEGIN TRAN;
    DELETE FROM OUTPUT TABLE WHERE ID = (1,2,3,4 etc)
    INSERT INTO OUTPUT TABLE Values (1,2,3,4 etc) 
COMMIT TRAN;
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: These are considered distinct SET operations within the same transaction/scope.  So, yes, there should be no locking from within the transaction.  That is not to say that other requests for these rows will be without locking.

Comment: is the first query always executed first?, I executed this query 10 x and it always execute the DELETE Statement first

Comment: Yes. It will always execute sequentially. The transaction doesn't change this. See the Workers section here [Understanding how SQL Server executes a query](http://rusanu.com/2013/08/01/understanding-how-sql-server-executes-a-query/). You might consider `MERGE` though if on 2008+.

Comment: @MartinSmith, Merge is too far for my requirements, anyway  if it always executed sequentially why there are some query uses `GO` after each statement?<-not related to my question above but i'm curious

Comment: The deleted and inserted rows will be locked for the duration of the transaction, with the statements executed sequentially. Be aware that if you have more than one of these transactions running concurrently, you might experience blocking/deadlocking, particularly if the same ID values are specified.  The values in the database will reflect the last committed transaction.

Comment: @DanGuzman-SQLServerMVP, how you identify this duration of transaction? is there a time limit for transaction?

Comment: There is no limit on transaction duration enforced by SQL Server.  However, client APIs have a CommandTimeout properly that specifies the maximum duration for a query (default 30 seconds).  The client API will cancel the query when the limit is exceeded.  This will rollback the currently exuting statement but not the entire transaction unless XACT_ABORT ON is specified (recommended). With XACT_ABORT OFF, the entire transaction rollback will occur when an explicit rollback is executed, the connection physically closed, or the pooled connection reused.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Within a transaction all write locks (all locks acquired for modifications) must obey the [strict two phase locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_locking) rule. One of the consequences is that a write (X) lock acquired in a transaction cannot be released until the transaction commits. So yes, the DELETE and INSERT will execute sequentially and all locks acquired during the DELETE will be retained while executing the INSERT.

Keep in mind that deleting 500k rows in a transaction will escalate the locks to one table lock, see [Lock Escalation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184286(v=sql.105).aspx).

Deleting 500k rows and inserting 500k rows in a single transaction, while maybe correct, is a bad idea. You should avoid such large units of works, long transaction, if possible. Long transactions pin the log in place, create blocking and contention, increase recovery and DB startup time, increase SQL Server resource consumption (locks require memory).

You should consider doing the operation in small batches (perhaps 10000 rows at time), use [MERGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) instead of DELETE/INSERT (if possible) and, last but not least, consider a partitioned sliding window 
implementation, see [How to Implement an Automatic Sliding Window in a Partitioned Table](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964122(v=sql.90).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation on TRANSACTION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> BEGIN TRANSACTION represents a point at which the data referenced by a
>   connection is logically and physically consistent. If errors are
>   encountered, all data modifications made after the BEGIN TRANSACTION
>   can be rolled back to return the data to this known state of
>   consistency. **Each transaction lasts until either it completes without
>   errors and COMMIT TRANSACTION is issued to make the modifications a
>   permanent part of the database, or errors are encountered and all
>   modifications are erased with a ROLLBACK TRANSACTION statement**.
>
> BEGIN TRANSACTION starts a local transaction for the connection
>   issuing the statement. **Depending on the current transaction isolation
>   level settings, many resources acquired to support the Transact-SQL
>   statements issued by the connection are locked by the transaction
>   until it is completed with either a COMMIT TRANSACTION or ROLLBACK
>   TRANSACTION statement**. Transactions left outstanding for long periods
>   of time can prevent other users from accessing these locked resources,
>   and also can prevent log truncation.
>
> Although BEGIN TRANSACTION starts a local transaction, it is not
>   recorded in the transaction log until the application subsequently
>   performs an action that must be recorded in the log, such as executing
>   an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement. An application can perform
>   actions such as acquiring locks to protect the transaction isolation
>   level of SELECT statements, but nothing is recorded in the log until
>   the application performs a modification action.