# Database deadlock while using transaction

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, async-await, npoco

```
public async Task<T> Method1(){      
    using (var transaction = Conn.GetTransaction())
            {
                await Conn.DeleteMany<M1>().Where(x => (x.d == dId).ExecuteAsync();
                foreach (var l in listData)
                {
                    await Conn.InsertAsync(l);
                }
                transaction.Complete();
            }
    }


public async Task<T> callerMethod(){
   var res = await serivce.Method1();
}

for(int i = 0; i <25; i++){
    callerMethod();
}
```

When I call this through web api [called it through a loop > 25 times]. some records are inserted and some gets a "Deadlock" message.

When I removed the "using(transaction)" block it worked fine. But, I believe we need to have "using(transaction) block.

Comment: Does this [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26338431/delete-and-insert-inside-one-transaction-sql)

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is a mix of accesses to the database, sometimes through a transaction and sometimes outside the transaction. This causes a locking problems - resources locked inside at transaction can't be locked again from outside the transaction. And that's the deadlock.

Since you want a transaction, I would switch to a `TransactionScope` instead, it should be carried across async calls.

Comment: I cannot find TransactionScope in NPoco